# About oracle sql group by 'not a group by expression'

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

Oracle 10g ,the sql throws exception:"not a group by expression"

```
select count(*)
        from (
            select h.personal_info_id pid,h.hbsag hbsag,h.sgpt sgpt,MAX(h.date_reported)
            from health_checkup_info h
            inner join personal_info p on h.personal_info_id = p.id
            where
                h.deleted = 0
                and h.date_reported is not null
                and h.hbsag in(1,2)
                and p.deleted = 0

            group by h.personal_info_id
        ) t where t.hbsag=1 and t.sgpt>=20
```

Then, I changed the 'group by' params, add 'h.hbsag' 'h.sgpt', like:

```
group by h.personal_info_id,h.hbsag,h.sgpt
```

But the result is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone,now I have already solved the problem.The query is:

```
select count(*)
        from (
            select h.personal_info_id pid,h.hbsag,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by h.personal_info_id order by h.date_reported desc) r
            from health_checkup_info h
            inner join personal_info p on h.personal_info_id = p.id
            where
                h.deleted = 0
                and h.date_reported is not null
                and h.hbsag in(1,2)
                and p.deleted = 0

        ) t where t.hbsag=2 and r=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add all the columns that are not part of aggregate functions. Try this.

```
select count(*) from 
( 
    select h.personal_info_id pid,h.hbsag hbsag,h.sgpt sgpt,MAX(h.date_reported) 
    from health_checkup_info h inner join personal_info p on h.personal_info_id = p.id 
    where h.deleted = 0 and h.date_reported is not null and h.hbsag in(1,2) and p.deleted = 0
    group by h.personal_info_id ,h.hbsag ,h.sgpt 
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Oracle's behavior, all selected columns except aggregate function must be grouped by.

```
select count(*)
        from (
            select h.personal_info_id pid,h.hbsag hbsag,h.sgpt sgpt,MAX(h.date_reported)
            from health_checkup_info h
            inner join personal_info p on h.personal_info_id = p.id
            where
                h.deleted = 0
                and h.date_reported is not null
                and h.hbsag in(1,2)
                and p.deleted = 0

            group by h.personal_info_id,h.hbsag,h.sgpt
        ) t
```

### Update:

As you are just using the `count`, What is need to fetch other columns?? try this..

```
select count(*)
        from (
            select h.personal_info_id pid,MAX(h.date_reported)
            from health_checkup_info h
            inner join personal_info p on h.personal_info_id = p.id
            where
                h.deleted = 0
                and h.date_reported is not null
                and h.hbsag in(1,2)
                and p.deleted = 0

            group by h.personal_info_id
        ) t;
```

Comment: You don't need to specify column alias in the group by clause. I think it is a copy/paste thing :)

Comment: @manurajhada,Thank you! But if use 'group by h.personal_info_id,h.hbsag,h.sgpt', the result is not correct. 
For example,use 'group by h.personal_info_id',the result is 2640.However,use 'group by h.personal_info_id,h.hbsag,h.sgpt',the result is 2641.Why?

Comment: yeah you are right let me update the query, just an another logic to achieve your goal..

Comment: @manurajhada  No,no,no.I need the h.hbsag,h.sgpt.and use it again filtered.

"   group by h.personal_info_id
        ) t where h.hbsag=1 and h.sgpt>=20   "

Comment: what is your absolute requirement??

Comment: @manurajhada

For example:

select count(*)
        from (
            select h.personal_info_id,h.hbsag hbsag,h.sgpt sgpt, MAX(h.date_reported)
            from health_checkup_info h
            inner join personal_info p on h.personal_info_id = p.id
            where
                h.deleted = 0
                and h.date_reported is not null
                and h.hbsag in(1,2)
                and p.deleted = 0
                and h.sgpt>=0 
            group by h.personal_info_id
        ) t  where t.hbsag=2 and t.sgpt>=20.0

Comment: Use this query... `    select count(*) from ( select h.personal_info_id,MAX(h.date_reported) from health_checkup_info h inner join personal_info p on h.personal_info_id = p.id where h.deleted = 0 and h.date_reported is not null and t.hbsag=2 and p.deleted = 0 and t.sgpt>=20.0 group by h.personal_info_id ) t `